# Compile C# Code In The Application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, compilation

I want some code that compiles the code that is in my TextBox (for example). What I mean is I want to compile code after running the program. How can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See this article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

Here's the sample code they provide:

```
var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
ICodeCompiler icc = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();

var parameters = new CompilerParameters()
{
    GenerateExecutable = true,
    OutputAssembly = Output,
};
CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, sourceString);

if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
{
    foreach(CompilerError error in results.Errors)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text
            + "Line number " + error.Line
            + ", Error Number: " + error.ErrorNumber
            + ", '" + error.ErrorText + ";"
            + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine
            ;
    }
}
```

As Aliostad has mentioned in his answer, be careful with this solution, though.  You will need to make sure your compiled code ends up in its own `AppDomain`, otherwise you will experience memory leaks.

See this related question on how to load the code into a separate `AppDomain`:

[How can I prevent CompileAssemblyFromSource from leaking memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799373/how-can-i-prevent-compileassemblyfromsource-from-leaking-memory)

Comment: BTW this code sample is only minimally edited.  I'd personally use a `StringBuilder` on that error message loop, and overwrite the text box's text rather than appending to it.

Answer (score 17):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx.aspx).

**Just be careful**, any code that is compiled and loaded, cannot be unloaded. This can cause **memory leak**, i.e. if someone keeps typing and changing the code and compiling it, assemblies get loaded and you will ultimately run out of memory.

One solution is to create a **second AppDomain** and load the assembly in there and when not needed, unload the AppDomain.