# Compiling C# Code in Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I just have one question regarding C#.

I have downloaded Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express to write the C# code.

Now, I want to compile the code using the same visual C#. Can I?

I have searched for a method to compile the code but all of the methods I founded are talking about command line 'cmd'.
I tried using it but it gives me that "csc is not recognized as an internal or external command ....." although that the directory I was in is the same as the C# code directory

I want to compile and see the results in the output.

This is the original code to compile:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Project1
{
    class Example1_1
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // display “Hello World!” on the screen
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            // display the current date and time
            System.Console.WriteLine("The current date and time is " +
            System.DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

and the result of pressing F6 'build' is:

> ------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Release x86 ------
>   Project1 -> C:\Users\Ali Alnufaili\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\Project1\bin\Release\Project1.exe
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

If you have any suggestion, till me please. ^_^

Comment: Have you tried pressing F7 or Ctrl-B? Or even just going to the Build menu. Or am I missing something?

Comment: if you want to compile code in another app [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944036/compile-c-sharp-code-in-the-application) is your answer

Comment: Use the pre-configured shell: "`Visual Studio Command Prompt`". From there you can run the `msbuild` command on your solution file. If you want to do that automatically, just copy all the environment variables values from that shell into your script.

Answer (score 2):

Just press this button:

[image]

or hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to compile and run your code.

**EDIT:**

So you are running a console application and write some text to the console. Maybe your problem is that the console window pops up and closes immediately?

Try adding `System.Console.ReadKey();` at the bottom of your Main method. Then the console window will stay open until you hit a key.

Or go the directory where your compiled program is (looks like it is C:\Users\Ali Alnufaili\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\Project1\bin\Release), open a command prompt (in windows explorer, hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and press the right mouse button and choose *Open command prompt here*), and run the executable in the command prompt (just type *Project1.exe* and hit enter)

Comment: Nice theme for VS. Which one is it?

Comment: @George http://www.nerdpad.com/visual-studio/visual-studio-2010-dark-expression-blend-color-theme

Comment: Thanks MR. dkson .. Although that it disappears very fast, I have tried to print-screen the console and I find the same result in the code. Thanks and I'll try to find the soulution you write to keep the console open.

Answer (score 0):

If you've created a project in Visual Studio, you should be able to simply use the "build" option from the menus/toolbars.

If you've got the default C# key bindings, I believe <kbd>F6</kbd> is a shortcut to start under the debugger.

Comment: I have added the code and the result of using F6 'Build'. I don't know why I can't see the outputs. I mean the "Hello World"!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have used some tutorial for the example. Did the tutorial not mention pressing <kbd>**F5**</kbd> to compile and run the application?

Your Build output says your program has compiled successfully, but to start your application, too, you need to press <kbd>**F5**</kbd>.

Also, currently your program will immediately exit when done. To make it wait, add the following line at the end:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

That will let you see your output and then the program will wait until you press enter.