# Find parameters and type with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I am reading out .cs-files and want to store all parameters per method with at least two parameters.
So every two word-combination between paranthesses like follows:

```
public static void MyFunction(string Param1, int Param2, List<string> Param3)
```

It should extract `string Param1`, `int Param2` and `List<string> Param3` into a collection. There is always a minimum of two parameters when using this.

So far I got the following Regex:

```
([A-Za-z0-9<>]+\s[a-z0-9]+)
```

This scans over the entire method header so includes `public static` as a match too.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: In your application, compile the code from the .cs files and then use reflection to extract the necessary information. The compilation step would also serve as a check whether the code in question is proper C#. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944036/compile-c-sharp-code-in-the-application) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments) for further information...

Comment: Why are you using regex for this? Parsing code is a solved problem, you don't need to solve it again. You should use [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) for this.

Comment: Because there is no need or way to compile this. These are .cs files from multiple projects that are not related in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just seems much easier to do without using Regex.  You'll obviously need something to identify the function header, but once you know you have a function header just break out the parameters like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string functionHeader = "public static void MyFunction(string Param1, int Param2, List<string> Param3)";
        string parameters = functionHeader.Substring(functionHeader.IndexOf("(") + 1)
                                          .Replace(", ", ",")
                                          .Replace(")", String.Empty);

        List<string> parametersCollection = new List<string>(parameters.Split(','));
        parametersCollection.ForEach(pc => Console.WriteLine(pc));
    }
}
```

Results:

```
string Param1
int Param2
List<string> Param3
```