# Runtime compilation generates a file that can't be removed

Tags: c#, runtime-compilation

I have this console type thing that accepts a line of C# code, wraps it up in some surrounding code and compiles it into an assembly. Then, I invoke the method from that assembly, output the result and that's it.

The problem is, the assembly needs to have a name so I can set it as a friend assembly so it could access the non-public classes. I named it "console".

Everything worked as expected but the problem is that I can't run a second script after one has finished because the file named "console" already exists in the directory and can't be overwritten.

I've tried Disposing of everything that has a Dispose method. I've tried manually deleting the file with File.Delete. Nothing helped.

So here's the code I'm using. I hope someone can help me.

```
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var param = new CompilerParameters();
param.GenerateInMemory = false;
param.GenerateExecutable = false;
param.OutputAssembly = "console";
param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(param,
@"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace FireflyGL
{
class DebugConsole
{
    static void Run(StringWriter writer)
    {
        var stdOut = Console.Out;
        Console.SetOut(writer);
        " + input.Text + @"
        Console.SetOut(stdOut);
    }
}
}");
            if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < results.Errors.Count; ++i)
                {
                    PushText(results.Errors[i].ErrorText);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    var writter = new StringWriter();
                    results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("FireflyGL.DebugConsole").GetMethod("Run", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(null, new object[] { writter });
                    PushText(writter.ToString());
                    history.Add(input.Text);
                    currentHistory = history.Count;
                    input.Text = "";
                    writter.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
            provider.Dispose();
            File.Delete(results.CompiledAssembly.Location);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to unload the assembly to get rid of all the references. Unfortunately, you can't do that. You can however unload an [`AppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) and provided you reference your assembly in that `AppDomain`, it will be unloaded as well.

If you don't care about creating a memory leak, you could also just create unique names for your assembly (`console1`, `console2` etc.)...

Comment: I did see an example online where the AppDomain was used but I don't really understand how.
How do I make my assembly be referenced in a certain AppDomain?

Comment: Never mind. I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799373/how-can-i-prevent-compileassemblyfromsource-from-leaking-memory

Comment: Is there any other way to go about it? I've been playing around and AppDomain is giving me tons of trouble. I need to be able to send object references to the script but then it throws a weird "object not serializable" exception.

Comment: @Darwin, I'm sorry, I don't know enough about AppDomains myself. Your objects need to derive from a special base class, though. Was it `MarshalByRef`?

Comment: That's why I'm looking for other options because I'm in a situation where I can't make everything derive from MarshalByRef.