# Compile run-time C# Script with existing type

Tags: c#

I am not really sure that i am picked right title.
But here i will try to explain the details what i want to do.

Currently I am developing simple 2d game engine for my own game.
Let's say i have 4 classes:

- `Scene` and `SceneObject`: There is `SceneObject[] Objects` variable in `Scene` class which represent Objects in Scene (SceneObject could be a text, image, button etc. For text it will be SceneObject.Text, for image it will be SceneObject.Image and so on).
- `ContentManager`: The class that handle image source for `SceneObject.Image`, all Image is stored in this class (Where "Image" is `System.Drawing.Image` type)
- `Log`: Simple Class to logging

What i want is Loading the `SceneObject` from C# Script, but in that script, i want to allow the script writer to interact with `ContentManager` (and all classes that may i made in my project, like the `Log` class)

Here the example of C# Code that to be compiled in Run-time (let's say its called "ExampleScript.cs"):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using Engine.Graphics;
using Engine.UI;

namespace Engine
{
    public class Example : Scene
    {
        public SceneObject.Button BtnExample;
        public SceneObject.Text LblExample;
        public Example()
        {
            // This will throw an exception if Example.png isn't exist in the ContentManager
            BtnExample = new SceneObject.Button(ContentManager.GetImage("Example.png"));
            LblExample = new SceneObject.Text("Hello World!");

            // This is the plus for C# Run-Time Code
            // Allow writer to add customization for each SceneObject
            BtnExample.Rotate(10);
            BtnExample.Color = Color.White;
            // and so on
            // I believe complicated effect / customization can be done easier than loading from plain text file (and it's somehow look cooler LOL)

            // Add it to "Objects" variable
            Add(LblExample, BtnExample);
            Log.WriteLine("SceneLoaded!");
        }
    }
}
```

and then i compile and get all `SceneObject` like this:

```
try
{
    Script SceneScript = new Script("ExampleScript.cs");
    Scene Example = SceneScript.Compile();
    SceneObject[] Objects = Example.Objects;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Compile Error here
    // Something like "'Example.png' isn't exist in content manager"
}
```

So how can i do this?

I tried to search on Google, but what i found is just something like compiling console application in run-time, that's not enough for me :\

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: thanks for what. This "question" is somewhat unclear in what your question is.

Comment: How can I compile the script in run-time? and I want the script is able to interact with the classes that i made (like `SceneObject`, `ContentManager` etc etc)

Comment: You could compile your script at run time with roslyn too if i recall correctly. That requires .net-4.5 if that's an option for you. It's an interesting topic either way

Comment: You can compile any string into a method by doing this: http://mattephraim.com/blog/2009/01/02/treating-c-like-a-scripting-language/  and for more detail try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799373/how-can-i-prevent-compileassemblyfromsource-from-leaking-memory

Comment: Thank you, that thread help me a lot!

Comment: Thank you for @Moby-Disk! this link help me a lot:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799373/how-can-i-prevent-compileassemblyfromsource-from-leaking-memory

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/) library.   In particular, take a look at their documentation around the 'type-sharing' pattern, which I think will do exactly what you are looking for (albeit you need to use their runtime library to do it)

Comment: The documentation makes CS-Script look like a whole .NET runtime.  Is it really just a wrapper for the CompileAssemblyFromSource method?

Comment: It's really just a wrapper (but with a lot of utility beyond what I would consider a basic wrapper), but the doc is definitely a little misleading there.  Looks like there is also some support for Mono and alternative CLRS, although I have no idea how deep that goes.